# Does there exist a $4\times4$ matrix $A$ such that $A$ and $A^2$ are not normal but $A^3$ is normal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, examples-counterexamples

I'm asked to provide a proof or a counterexample for this claim:

Does there exist a $4\times4$ matrix $A$ such that $A$, $A^2$ is not normal, but $A^3$ is normal.

Any ideas are welcome Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are your thoughts? What have you tried?

Comment: @lisayarus I've honestly given a lot of thought but I cannot seem to come up with a counterexample. Dealing with $4\times4$ matrices is quite difficult tbh. Any help would be nice

Comment: If $4x4$ is too difficult to start. How about $2\times 2$ such that $A$ is not normal, but $A^2$ is? This will probably give you an idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a counterexample where $A$ is nonsingular. Let $C=\pmatrix{0&-1\\ 1&-1}$ be the companion matrix of the characteristic polynomial $x^2+x+1=0$. One can verify that $C$ and $C^2$ are not normal but $C^3=I_2$. Now take $A=\pmatrix{C\\ &I_2}$ or $A=\pmatrix{C\\ &C}$.

Answer (score 3):

Note: An upper triangular matrix is normal iff it is diagonal.

This suggests
$$\begin{pmatrix}0&1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}. $$

Comment: Unless I make a silly mistake, this doesn't work as $A^3$ is non-zero and nilpotent so it is also not normal. However, $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 &0 \end{pmatrix}$ works as $A$ and $A^2$ are non-zero and nilpotent while $A^3 = 0$ is normal.